# Inject Java Applet onto page?

Tags: java

I know it's possible to inject JavaScript onto a Salesforce page (with sidebar components, which are unfortunately going away this summer), but I'm wondering if it's possible to do the same thing with a Java app?

Comment: what sort of java app you want to embed ? did u check if its possible thru Canvas ?